# sfdx force:source:push - always pushes everything

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm following the [App Development with Salesforce DX](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/sfdx_get_started/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_build_app) Trailhead module in order to finally learn it. I've been doing one step at a time from Trailhead, adding the custom Account Field, Apex Controller, and the Lightning Component, and after every step I executed `sfdx force:source:push` command.

What I expected the output of `sfdx force:source:push` command to be after each step was the addition of only the new component that I created since the last `sfdx force:source:push` command, something like it is suggested in Trailhead:

[image]

However, the command always returns back a message like it added **all** the components I have locally, and not just the components that changed:

[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening, or if this is expected? I don't think that this is expected behavior, so what am I doing wrong?

Also, I checked the org, and the `LastModifiedDate` is not being updated for the metadata that hasn't been updated locally, even though they are reported as added by the `push` command.

**EDIT**

Included below is the output of `tree .sfdx`:

[image]

Comment: Can you include the output of `tree .sfdx`?

Comment: And no, this isn't normal behavior. In fact, it's *really hard* to get it to push anything once it's convinced that the files are up to date.

Comment: @sfdcfox I included the output of `tree .sfdx`. I hope it helps. Can you share what you are looking for in it?

Comment: I have observed that as well to. Seems like a bug

Comment: Inside “test-kzjg25fjq3ni@example.com” folder there should be a file called sourcepath-infos that should have the tracking files and last updated time stamp. Not sure the exact cause but have you tried creating a new scratch org and pushing to it?

Comment: Creating a new scratch org fixed the problem, the changes are now tracked as expected. Thank you. FYI, I haven't .gitignored the .sfdx folder initially, and I was switching branches, so that might have caused the problem. Not sure, though.